# Make FSPDFViewCtrl scrollable only horizontally?

Tags: ios, foxit

Is it possible to let `FSPDFViewCtrl` be scrolled only horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible

I haven't used the library you are mentioning but i can suggest you right direction for your solution.

For **Swift 3, 4**:

```
[YOUR SCROLLABLE VIEW].contentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1000)
```

same will work for Objective C

please note:
if you set width 0 in content size it means you are blocking horizontal scrolling
and if you are setting height 0 then it means you are blocking vertical scrolling